# How to make one-dimensional k-means clustering using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

**My question:**

I have searched through available Ruby gems to find one that performs k-means clustering. I've found quite a few: [kmeans](http://github.com/id774/kmeans), [kmeans-clustering](https://github.com/vaneyckt/kmeans-clustering), [reddavis-k_means](https://github.com/reddavis/K-Means) and [k_means_pp](https://github.com/ollie/k_means_pp). My problem is that none of the gems deals with one-dimensional k-means clustering. They all expect input like this:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

My input looks like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Hence my question: *How do I perform a one-dimensional k-means clustering using Ruby?*

**The context (my task):**

I have 100 input values:

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 10, 16, 18, 22, 22, 35, 50, 50

Each value represents a response time, i.e. the number of minutes it took for some customer service agent to respond to an email from a customer. So the first value 0 indicates that the customer only waited 0 minutes for a response.

I need to find out how many fast, medium-fast and slow response time instances there is. In other words, I want to cut my input values up in 3 pools, and then count how many there are in each pool.

The complicating factor is that I based on the overall slope steepness have to figure out where to make the cuts. There is no fixed definition of fast, medium-fast and slow. The first cut (between fast and medium-fast) should occur where the steepness of the slope starts to increase more drastically than before. The second cut (between medium-fast and slow) should occur when an even more dramatic steepness increase occur.

Here is a graphical representation of the input values.

[image]

In the above example, common sense would probably define fast as 0-3, because there are many instances of 0, 1, 2, and 3. 4-8 or 4-10 looks like common sense choices for medium-fast. But how to determine something like this mathematically? If the response times were generally faster, then the customers would be expecting this, so an even smaller increase towards the end should trigger the cut.

**Finishing notes:**

I did find the gem [davidrichards-kmeans](http://github.com/davidrichards/kmeans) that deals with one-dimensional k-means clustering, but it don't seem to work properly (the example code raises a syntax error).

Comment: Let's say your data is `[1, 4, 6, 7, 8]`. Then you can just do 2-dimensional clustering with the data `[[1, 0], [4, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0]]`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k-means is the wrong tool for this job anyway.

It's not designed for fitting an exponential curve.

Here is a much more sound proposal for you:

Look at the plot, mark the three points, and then you have your three groups.

Or look at quantiles... Report the median response time, the 90% quantile, and the 99% quantile...

Clustering is about **structure discovery** in multivariate data. It's probably not what you want it to be, sorry.

If you insist on trying k-means, try encoding the data as

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

and check if the results are at least a little bit what you want them to be (also remember that k-means is randomized. Running it multiple times may yield very different results).